# Register mailto protocol to custom program on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, mailto

I would like to register my program to handle the `mailto`  protocol.

I have seen these answers

- [How to register custom program to handle mailto protocol on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105258/how-to-register-custom-program-to-handle-mailto-protocol-on-windows-7)
- [Register Windows program with the mailto protocol programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231/register-windows-program-with-the-mailto-protocol-programmatically)

I tried adding a new key or modifying the existing key at this path: 
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\URLAssociations\MAILTO\Userchoice`.

Additionally, I added my program to to the `HKCR` root, but that did not make my program appear in the select list.

Also, for testing purposes, I tried changing the classname value of the mailto key at this path: 
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\GoogleChrome\Capabilities\
URLAssociations` to the classname of my program. This actually worked, but instead of hacking into Google Chrome, I’d rather add my own registry key.

How can I add my program as a legitimate handler for the `mailto` protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample mail client registration - To register with Default Programs / modern Default Apps. You can modify it accordingly, leaving out non-essential parts.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

;RegisteredApplications
;----------------------
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\RegisteredApplications]
"MyMail"="Software\\Clients\\Mail\\MyMail\\Capabilities"


;Clients Key (The path mentioned for MyMail in RegisterdApplications key)
;------------------------------------------------------------------------
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail\MyMail]
@="MyMail"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail\MyMail\Capabilities]
"ApplicationDescription"="Superfast, Light-weight Mail Client for Windows"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail\MyMail\Capabilities\FileAssociations]
".eml"="MyMail.eml"
".nws"="MyMail.nws"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail\MyMail\Capabilities\StartMenu]
"Mail"="MyMail"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail\MyMail\Capabilities\UrlAssociations]
"mailto"="MyMail.mailto"


;Then create handlers for MyMail.eml, MyMail.nws, MyMail.mailto as referenced above

;EML File Type Handler
;---------------------
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MyMail.eml]
@="MyMail EML Handler"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MyMail.eml\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Windows Mail\\WinMail.exe\" -eml \"%1\""


;NWS File Type Handler
;---------------------
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MyMail.nws]
@="MyMail NEWS Handler"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MyMail.nws\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Windows Mail\\WinMail.exe\" -news \"%1\""


;MAILTO Protocol Handler
;---------------------
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MyMail.mailto]
@="MyMail MAILTO Handler"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MyMail.mailto\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Windows Mail\\WinMail.exe\" -mailto \"%1\""
```

I've uploaded the same in this [Pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/mSrL6XrB).

For official documentation, refer [Default Programs Registration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144154%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) at MSDN. Although the docs state it's not valid for Windows 10, it certainly applies (and works perfectly) in Windows 10. The registration part hasn't changed a bit in Windows 10.

Also, see:
[Windows 10 program default settings - Microsoft Community](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/windows-10-program-default-settings/0e485300-360d-4dd7-90d0-f48cef7dd13e)

Answer (score 0):

mailto links didn't work with this registry patch. So I modified this line:

```
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Windows Mail\\WinMail.exe\" -mailto \"%1\""
```

into this

```
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Windows Mail\\WinMail.exe\" /mailurl:\"%1\""
```

Then, to associate all protocols to Windows Mail, I opened Control Panel > Predefined programs > Set predefined programs and made necessary changes.

Comment: As it is worded currently, this should be a comment to the other answer and not an answer of its own, but of course you'd need some additional bit of reputation for that...

Comment: One more note: when I click on e-mail addresses in Firefox, no new message window appears, but there's a workaround for this too:

Create a batch file like this:

    @echo off
    "c:\program files\windows mail\winmail.exe" /mailurl:%1

Save this batch file as "WinmailFF.bat" inside for example "c:\program files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox"

Go to Firefox,Tools,Options,Applications

Search for "Mailto", select "Other", then select the batch file you created. If you don't find it, enter "*.bat" to show it in the folder.

This should make "mailto:" links working in FF with WinMail&Win10