# HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail constantly overwritten

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, windows-registry, thunderbird

Here is my problem.

We are using Office 365 in company but we don't want the Microsoft Outlook. Our primary mail client is Mozilla Thunderbird.

The problem is that registry value set in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail is constantly overwritten upon system start - from Mozilla Thunderbird to Microsoft Outlook.

So far i've tried to create shortcut inside shell:startup to .reg file with this contents

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail]
@="Mozilla Thunderbird"
```

I can't delete or disable Outlook without uninstalling whole Office 365. Also Outlook is not run by any user on any computer - still this value is changing itself...

Is there any way to prevent HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail from future edit by system?

Comment: Isn’t the preferred mail client a per-user setting? Also note that Windows is now more vigilant about what it considers unwanted changes to default programs. Have you tried changing it with the user interface?

Comment: "I can't delete or disable Outlook without uninstalling whole Office 365." - You actually can it just would involve configuring the installer to do that.  **You could also create an Office installer that doesn't even install Outlook.**

Comment: I don't recommend this solution but you could change the permissions on the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail` key itself.  You will likely receive errors if you did that, I am not willing to try that, but there are numerous resources that have suggested a similar solution to preventing the default application from being changed when a feature update is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You all for help!

I've ended up using Office Customization Tool (https://config.office.com/) and tutorial from here (http://woshub.com/install-custom-app-office/)

Everything works now as it should.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 0):

Except changing it with user interface, based on my research, I found a similar thread :[Register mailto protocol to custom program on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1097511/register-mailto-protocol-to-custom-program-on-windows-10), which mentioned a sample mail client registration - To register with Default Programs / modern Default Apps.

Also, we may be able to change default mail client using group policy via create an app associations XML file and deploy your app associations XML file through GPO, for more information, you could refer to this [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/troubleshoot/group-policy/configure-email-client-using-policy).

Hope that would be helpful to you.