# Making EUDORA.EXE the mailto mail program

Tags: windows, email, microsoft-outlook, mailto

Up until Office365 (2016) my trusted Eudora worked fine on Windows 3.1 to 10 - but now OUTLOOK 2016 seems to write over all the connections.  So I have lost the mailto function.  (Yes, Eudora is very old but it works well for me - really well so I am keen to continue with it and my 1 million+ messages).

The text in the how to make Google Chrome mailer work in this thread as the mailto mailer is close to my need but I lost track, apologies, to the various suggestions.

What has gone is the Default App list so I can't select Eudora - that would trigger the mailto. Eudora is listed under file types: .mbx  but how to make the .mailto work?

(I do use Eudora to read both my university SMTP and other POP accounts.  All works really easily.)

The frustrating thing is that clearly, the Registry has a setting that defines everything clearly - so one or more programs have intercepted the Eudora setting for mailto when the 2016 Office/Outlook was installed.  But which one?

Comment: Hey Martin, welcome to Superuser :)

This answer *might* have what you're looking for, it involves tweaking the registry to set whatever program you want as the `mailto` handler. Give it a look maybe? https://superuser.com/questions/1097511/register-mailto-protocol-to-custom-program-on-windows-10

Comment: Agree with Mikey, you could try the suggestion as that article mentioned, and if your issue has any update, you could post back here.

Comment: Does your issue has any update? If so, please feel free to post back.